# How to build FSM when there are too many states?

Tags: verilog, fsm

I am working on a vending machine project and trying to build a state machine, as I saw from other examples. The machine that I am trying to build holds up to 100 dollars. And it takes nickel, dime and quarter. So, I should define about 2000 states one by one. How can I build an FSM in an easier way? I just want a suggestion to proceed.

Thanks :)

Comment: What do these 2000 states represent?  Can you not just implement a bunch of counters?  (Which are, of course, FSMs)

Comment: 2000 states represent every 5 cent increment of sum of the money up to $100. For example, $63.85 is a possible state for the machine.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you feel that every possible value of the machine's cash balance needs a separate state? That sounds like a poor use of a FSM.

Just use an integer register which holds the total balance of the machine, or separate registers which hold the number of various coins and bills and calculate the total from that.

States might be things like `process payment`, `dispense item`, or `refund change`. Not the balance of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have 2000 "states" doesn't mean you have to enumerate every single one of them in a case statement.

As others have mentioned, you need to store some of your state in counters.